# RVM fails to install Ruby 2.3.x

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-2.3

RVM fails, and hangs, when trying to install Ruby **2.3.x** (**2.3.1** in my case) on Manjaro 4.11.12, but this issue has been also reported on other operating systems such as openSUSE.

The error thrown is `Error in../../miniruby': corrupted double-linked list` but there are situations where RVM also points to OpenSSL or GCC.

Here is what I tried:

- Downgrading from GCC7 to GCC6 and even GCC5
- Installing openssl with the rvm pkg install command (`rvm pkg install openssl`)
- Doing a system update

Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a while to debug as the log files are not very explicit, most of them point to OpenSSL 1.0 some of them point towards GCC; also this issus can't be reproduced with newer Ruby versions such as 2.4.x.

It seems that the issue is from GCC7 and there is already an official patch released for it.

You can download the patch from https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/6655/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch and then run `rvm install 2.3.x --patch ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch%0`.

This should fix the issue and RVM won't complain anymore.